# programmatically include layout(i.e not xml) in android game

Tags: android, revmob

How to include layout programmatically in android without using xml layouts to display banner ads in android. I am creating a game App where i need to display banner ads in each and every game page. I have already included full screen revmob ads but i need to include banner ads. I used the following code but banner ads are not displaying

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/banner"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private CCGLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;
private boolean isCreated = false;
public static FrameLayout m_rootLayout;

public static String APPLICATION_ID = "514b9c57cce0500d00000001";
public static RevMob revmob;

// This is used to display Toast messages and is not necessary for your app
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (!isCreated) {
        isCreated = true;
    } else {
        return;
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     //admob widget

    revmob = RevMob.start(this, APPLICATION_ID);
     displayRevMob();

    mGLSurfaceView = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(mGLSurfaceView);


    CCDirector.sharedDirector().attachInView(mGLSurfaceView);

    getScaledCoordinate();

    Global.assetManager = getAssets();
    Global.context = this;
    Global.loadUserInfo();
    CCScene scene = CCScene.node();
    scene.addChild(new SplashScene(), -1);

    CCDirector.sharedDirector().runWithScene(scene);




    //-------------IAP-----------------------
    Log.d(TAG1, "Creating IAB helper.");
        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
        mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);
        Log.d(TAG1, "Starting setup.");
        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");

                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                    complain("Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
                    return;
                }

                // Hooray, IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we own.
                Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
                mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
            }
        });


      RevMobBanner banner = revmob.createBanner(this);
          ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.banner);
          view.addView(banner);

        Global.myActivity=this;
}
```

Comment: you used setContentView(mGLSurfaceView), so findViewById(R.id.banner) should return NULL. am i true? you should inflate a new view from your xml layout by LayoutInflater.

Comment: Yes its returning NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first create a new view from your xml layout file by LayoutInflater. then add the banner to it. here is a sample:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()); 
ViewGroup yourview = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);

RevMobBanner banner = revmob.createBanner(this);
yourview.addView(banner);
```

if you want use a linearlayout above your surfaceview, a simple way is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/banner"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

    <CCGLSurfaceView android:id="@+id/yoursurfaceview"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </CCGLSurfaceView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Mbt925 thank you for your reply Now i am getting banner Ad loaded in logcat but i am not able to see banner ad in emulator can you please tell me why i am not able to see banner Ad?

Comment: because the new layout you create, should be added to your screen layout (setContentView(mGLSurfaceView))! so add the new view to this mGLSurfaceView.

Comment: As i am new to android if you don't mind Can you please explain in more detail i did not get what you explained above. How to add new layout to screenlayout and also new view to mGLSurfaceView.

Comment: you wanna use a linearlayout in your surfaceview. you should create a new layout that contains both. i updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

The programmatic translation of your XML is;

```
LinearLayout lin=new LinearLayout(this);
lin.setLayoutsParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                      LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
lin.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

LinearLayout lin2=new LinearLayout(this);
lin2.setLayoutsParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

lin.addView(lin2);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **LayoutInflater**
For example

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layOut = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout_name, false, false);
//to fetch Views use 
TextView label_name = (TextView) layOut.findViewById(R.id.view_id_here);
```